# NullPointerException using Shiro

Tags: shiro

I'm adding shiro to an existing Web application(using spring mvc), but I always got NullPointerException.

Here are the error message:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/haha-web] threw exception [Filtered request failed.] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.SessionsSecurityManager.getSession(SessionsSecurityManager.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveContextSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:456)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:442)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:338)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:846)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Servlet.service() for servlet [static] in context with path [/haha-web] threw exception [Filtered request failed.] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.SessionsSecurityManager.getSession(SessionsSecurityManager.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveContextSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:456)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:442)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:338)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:846)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Servlet.service() for servlet [static] in context with path [/haha-web] threw exception [Filtered request failed.] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.SessionsSecurityManager.getSession(SessionsSecurityManager.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveContextSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:456)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolveSession(DefaultSecurityManager.java:442)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:338)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:846)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked the source code of Shiro, seems the sessionManager is Null.

Here are part of my shiro config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManagerConfigFile" value="classpath:spring/ehcache.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="credentialsMatcher" class="org.haha.security.credentials.RetryLimitHashedCredentialsMatcher">
        <constructor-arg ref="cacheManager"/>
        <property name="hashAlgorithmName" value="md5"/>
        <property name="hashIterations" value="2"/>
        <property name="storedCredentialsHexEncoded" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userRealm" class="org.haha.security.realm.UserRealm">
        <property name="operatorService" ref="operatorService"/>
        <property name="credentialsMatcher" ref="credentialsMatcher"/>
        <property name="cachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="authenticationCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="authenticationCacheName" value="authenticationCache"/>
        <property name="authorizationCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="authorizationCacheName" value="authorizationCache"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionIdGenerator" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.JavaUuidSessionIdGenerator"/>

    <bean id="sessionIdCookie" class="org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie">
        <constructor-arg value="sid"/>
        <property name="httpOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxAge" value="180000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionDAO" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO">
        <property name="activeSessionsCacheName" value="shiro-activeSessionCache"/>
        <property name="sessionIdGenerator" ref="sessionIdGenerator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionValidationScheduler" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.quartz.QuartzSessionValidationScheduler">
        <property name="sessionValidationInterval" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager">
        <property name="globalSessionTimeout" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="deleteInvalidSessions" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionValidationSchedulerEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionValidationScheduler" ref="sessionValidationScheduler"/>
        <property name="sessionDAO" ref="sessionDAO"/>
        <property name="sessionIdCookieEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionIdCookie" ref="sessionIdCookie"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="realm" ref="userRealm"/>
        <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticMethod" value="org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager"/>
        <property name="arguments" ref="securityManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/home"/>
        <property name="successUrl" value="/home"/>
        <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/home"/>
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /js/** = anon
                /api-js/** = anon
                /img/** = anon
                /css/** = anon
                /** = authc
            </value>
        </property>         
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm new to Shiro, and I've tried everything I could in the past 4 days T_T, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My web application will reload context on `ContextRefreshedEvent`(when `ApplicationContext` get initialized), I rewrite the code to avoid the reload, and the NullPointerException disappear. Though I didn't quite understand the logic, but it seems the reload make sessionManager become null. Hope someone can explain :-D.

Comment: For supplement: [discussion in shiro maillist](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/NullPointerException-using-Shiro-tc7580049.html)